# Why does it not shows JSON data in console log using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

When I code this in some file (say: test.html):

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.getJSON('https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source=techcrunch&sortBy=top&apiKey=my-api-key',function(json) {
        console.log(json);

    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

But if I do same thing in some other file say (main.js)

```
(function(){

$.getJSON('https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source=techcrunch&sortBy=top&apiKey=my-api-key',function(json) {
        console.log(json);

    });

});
```

The above code doesn't show any JSON data in console, I have added main.js in HTML.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because on the second snippet, the function doesn't execute at all.

Code below,

```
(function(){
     $.getJSON('... url ...', function(json) {
         console.log(json);
     };
});
```

Can be simplified into

```
(function(){});
```

Which doesn't execute at all. You need to put parenthesis on the end of the function to execute, like this:

```
(function(){}());
```

Or better yet, use the jquery document ready short-hand for proper execution after the page loaded.

```
$(function(){});
```

Hope it's help.

Comment: *"Or better yet..."* That's only useful if one needs to access DOM elements.

Comment: @FelixKling Yes Thanks I need to access DOM elements.

Answer (score 1):

You need to evoke the function you are creating in your main.js file. If you wrap code with `function() {}`, you are defining what the function is, but not calling it. You need to call it as well as define it.

```
(function(){

  $.getJSON('https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source=techcrunch&sortBy=top&apiKey=045089075bc74354be01b34f6335d32b',function(json) {
      console.log(json);
  });

})(); // parenthesis call the function
```